# Trouble with copulas: how do we justify its definition?

Tags: self-study, definition, copula

A bivariate function $C(u,v)$ that maps $[0,1]^{2}$ to $[0,1]$ is a copula if it satisfies the following two conditions:

(i) Boundary conditions:
\begin{align*}
C(u,0) = 0\\
C(0,v) = 0\\
C(u,1) = u\\
C(1,v) = v\\
C(1,1) = 1
\end{align*}

(ii) 2-increasing property:
\begin{align*}
C(u_{1},v_{1}) + C(u_{2},v_{2}) - C(u_{1},v_{2}) - C(u_{2},v_{1}) \geq 0,\quad u_{1}\leq u_{2}\,\,\text{and}\,\, v_{1}\leq v_{2}
\end{align*}

If $C(u,v)$ is twice differentiable, then the 2-increasing property is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^{2}C(u,v)}{\partial u\partial v} \geq 0
\end{align*}

My questions is: can someone tell me what motivates such definition? Moreover, could someone tell me how the last expression substitutes the second condition? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Copulas arise naturally as the cumulative distribution functions of random vectors whose components are uniformly distributed on [0, 1]. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29) is good in my opinion

Comment: The second question is answered by (a) taking limits to go from the finite difference inequality to the derivative inequality and (b) integrating the derivative inequality to obtain the finite difference inequality.

Comment: Dear whuber, thanks for the comment, but could you please provide a full answer to my question?